# How to print uniq number after?

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk

```
gawk '$9=="404" || $9=="403"' log.txt | gawk '{print $7}' |  sort -k7 | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

output:

```
28 /example/.comments
9 /example/example.atom.xml
8 /example/When/200x/2003/04/10/-big/Concorde.jpg
7 /example/When/200x/2006/03/30/-big/IMG_4613.jpg
6 /example/When/200x/2003/07/25/-big/guild-2.jpg
5 /example/Patti-Smith.png
```

how to print uniq number after name url? and print with numeration

```
1. /example/.comments - 28
2. /example/example.atom.xml - 9
3. /example/When/200x/2003/04/10/-big/Concorde.jpg - 8
4. /example/When/200x/2006/03/30/-big/IMG_4613.jpg - 7
5. /example/When/200x/2003/07/25/-big/guild-2.jpg - 6
6. /example/Patti-Smith.png - 5
7. /example/IMGP4289-2.png - 5
8. /example/IMGP4287.png - 5
9. /example/Image-Search-Mystery.png - 5
10. /example/Horses.png - 5
11. /example/When/200x/2004/02/27/-big/Unreal.png - 4
```

Comment: Just a comment: Combine your first two steps into `awk '$9=="404" || $9=="403" { print $7 }'`. Also use just `sort` before the `uniq` (there is no 7th field).

Comment: `gawk '$9=="404" || $9=="403"' log.txt | gawk '{print $7}'` = `gawk '$9 ~ /^40[34]$/{print $7}'`

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you , i am not good at regex , so I write like this :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following `awk` command will modify each input line so that the first field is copied to a new  last field and prefixed by a dash.  The 1st field is then replaced with the line number followed by a dot.

```
awk '{ $(NF+1) = "-"; $(NF+1) = $1; $1 = NR "."; print }'
```

So, combining the two `awk` calls with `sort | uniq -c` in your initial pipeline and tagging this onto the end:

```
awk '
    $9 ~ /^40[34]$/ { count[$7]++ }
    END             { for (a in count) print count[a], a }' log.txt |
sort -nr |
awk '{ $(NF+1) = "-"; $(NF+1) = $1; $1 = NR "."; print }'
```

---

If you happen to have GNU `awk` (commonly found on e.g. Linux systems), release 4.0 or later, then you may additionally do the `sort -nr` in `awk` too:

```
awk '
    $9 ~ /^40[34]$/ { count[$7]++ }
    END             { 
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
        for (a in count)
            print ++i ".", a, "-", count[a]
    }' log.txt
```