# Can i somehow manipulate with uniq number?

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk

```
read W

gawk '$9=="404" || $9=="403"' log.txt | gawk '{print $7}' |  sort -k7 | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '{ $(NF+1) = "-"; $(NF+1) = $1; $1 = NR "."; $(NF+1) = "-"; print}' | head -"$W"
```

i have this script that take input w and print w number of lines .

Output :

```
1. /example/.comments - 28 -
2. /example/example.atom.xml - 9 -
3. /example/When/200x/2003/04/10/-big/Concorde.jpg - 8 -
4. /example/When/200x/2006/03/30/-big/IMG_4613.jpg - 7 -
5. /example/When/200x/2003/07/25/-big/guild-2.jpg - 6 -
```

can i somehow take value from uniq and use it to find % from total number of errors? (uniq number*100/total amount of errors) (total number 87)

or can divide immediately after the diphis?

```
1. /example/.comments - 28 - 32.2%
2. /example/example.atom.xml - 9 - 10.3%
3. /example/When/200x/2003/04/10/-big/Concorde.jpg - 8 - 9.2%
4. /example/When/200x/2006/03/30/-big/IMG_4613.jpg - 7 - 8.0%
5. /example/When/200x/2003/07/25/-big/guild-2.jpg - 6 - 6.9%
```

Comment: Only the input from your [last question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/626238) and the last `gawk` command is interesting here. We don't need to know the whole pipeline of commands if your question lacks the original input from `log.txt`. It just confuses and makes it harder to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Awk approach is to
[read the file twice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32481877). In the first pass, compute the `t`otal
of the next to last field `$(NF-1)`.
In the second pass, calculate and append the percentage to the line.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{t+=$(NF-1); next}{printf "%s %.1f%\n", $0, 100*$(NF-1)/t}' file file
```